# Django Ajax Reorder Not Updating the Field in Database

Tags: python, html, django

I'm building a list of students by each class in the grade. I have a folder full of profile pictures for students downloaded into my img folder and a column within my model that maps the details (name, class, age, etc.) to the image name.

How do I tell my table to bring in the appropriate img for each student?

Below I have my code working to use a single image as a constant (e.g. student1's picture shows up for everyone).

list.html:

```
<table class="table table-hover" id="table-ajax">
  <thead class="thead-light">
    <tr>
      {% comment %} <th></th> {% endcomment %}
      <th style="width: 50px; text-align: center;"></th>
      <th>{{ object_list|verbose_name:'field:name' }}</th>
      <th>{{ object_list|verbose_name:'field:hometown' }}</th>
      <th>{{ object_list|verbose_name:'field:birthday' }}</th>
      <th>{{ object_list|verbose_name:'field:race' }}</th>
      <th>{{ object_list|verbose_name:'field:rank' }}</th>
      <th style="width: 50px; text-align: center;">Pictures</th>
      <th style="width: 160px; text-align: center;">Actions</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="order" data-url="{% url 'cms:reorder' model_name %}">
    {% include 'app/partials/pick_list_partial.html' %}
  </tbody>
```

partial-list.html:

```
{% for pick in object_list %}
<tr id="{{ pick.pk }}">
    <td><img src="{% static 'img/student1.jpg' %}" width="50" height="50"></td>
    <td><a href="{% url 'app:lead-list' pick.pk %}" title="Leads">{{ pick.name }}</a></td>
    <td>{{ pick.hometown }}</td>
    <td>{{ pick.birthday }}</td>
    <td>{{ pick.race }}</td>
    <td>{{ pick.rank }}</td>
    <td style="text-align: center;">
        <a href="{% url 'app:file-list' pick.pk %}" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm border-0" title="Files">
            <i class="fa fa-copy"></i></a></td>
    <td style="text-align: center;">
        <a href="{% get_object_url 'detail' pick %}" class="btn btn-outline-warning btn-sm border-0 ajax-load-form" title="View">
            <i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a>
        <a href="{% get_object_url 'update' pick %}" class="btn btn-outline-info btn-sm border-0 ajax-load-form" title="Edit">
            <i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>
        <a href="{% get_object_url 'delete' pick %}" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm border-0 ajax-load-form" title="Delete">
            <i class="fa fa-trash-alt"></i></a>
        <a href="" class="btn btn-sm border-0 reorder" title="Reorder">
            <i class="fa fa-sort text-secondary"></i></a>
    </td>
</tr>
{% empty %}
<tr class="table-warning nosort">
    <td colspan="100%" class="text-center"><small class="text-muted">No {{ model_verbose_name_plural|lower }}</small>
    </td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume, you have property `image_path` in your `pick` object that equals to `img/student1.jpg`. Then you should use it like this:

```
{% for pick in object_list %}
<tr id="{{ pick.pk }}">
    <td><img src="{% static pick.image_path %}" width="50" height="50"></td>
    <td><a href="{% url 'app:lead-list' pick.pk %}" title="Leads">{{ pick.name }}</a></td>
    <td>{{ pick.hometown }}</td>
    <td>{{ pick.birthday }}</td>
    <td>{{ pick.race }}</td>
    <td>{{ pick.rank }}</td>
    <td style="text-align: center;">
        <a href="{% url 'app:file-list' pick.pk %}" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm border-0" title="Files">
            <i class="fa fa-copy"></i></a></td>
    <td style="text-align: center;">
        <a href="{% get_object_url 'detail' pick %}" class="btn btn-outline-warning btn-sm border-0 ajax-load-form" title="View">
            <i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a>
        <a href="{% get_object_url 'update' pick %}" class="btn btn-outline-info btn-sm border-0 ajax-load-form" title="Edit">
            <i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>
        <a href="{% get_object_url 'delete' pick %}" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm border-0 ajax-load-form" title="Delete">
            <i class="fa fa-trash-alt"></i></a>
        <a href="" class="btn btn-sm border-0 reorder" title="Reorder">
            <i class="fa fa-sort text-secondary"></i></a>
    </td>
</tr>
{% empty %}
<tr class="table-warning nosort">
    <td colspan="100%" class="text-center"><small class="text-muted">No {{ model_verbose_name_plural|lower }}</small>
    </td>
</tr>
```